# BxSlider moved to the right in IE7

Tags: slideshow, bxslider

I'm using the [BxSlider jquery plugin](http://bxslider.com/) in [this website](http://www.doremilla.org/).

Everything work correctly, except in IE7, where the entire slideshow is moved toward right.

I concluded that the problem is the plugin because in other page where there isn't any slideshow but a single fixed page (as [this one](http://www.doremilla.org/studio_registrazione)) everything works fine.